# How do you boot a rails app on a remote server into Development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I totally apologize for being so naiive. But when I deploy to production, it is automatically boots up in production mode.

How do I alternatively boot this up in development mode?

Comment: What method are you using to start it on your server?

Comment: Just sending a command to nginx to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you are using to run your Rails application.

- If you are using Passenger for Apache, set
  `RailsEnv` to development in your vhost, then restart the web server. For Passenger on Nginx check here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_ruby_on_rails_specific_options
- If you are
  using mongrel or thin, it has an option for
  that. Check their docs
- If you are using `script/server` pass it as an argument: `script/server development`
- Or if you are using `rails server` (for rails 3): `rails server -e development`

Often you can also set the environment variable `RAILS_ENV` to do this as well, for example: `RAILS_ENV=development rails server`